# htaccess rewrite rule not matching

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, match

I want to match varriables on htaccess... Here is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([^/]*).mp4$ str.php?vid=$1&auth=$2&hash=$3
RewriteCond ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([^/]*).mp4?start=(.*)$ str.php?vid=$1&auth=$2&hash=$3&start=$4
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([^/]*).flv$ str.php?vid=$1&auth=$2&hash=$3
RewriteCond ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([^/]*).flv?start=(.*)$ str.php?vid=$1&auth=$2&hash=$3&start=$4
```

Everything works fine but there is a problem with `start` varriable. htaccess is not matching the `start` varriable. Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$4` variable when it should be `$5` since in your URL you are searching for `5` matches with `start=(.*)` being the 5th one.

However, try it this way with these two lines instead of the 4. Use the `QSA` flag and it will append the query string to the end if its included in the URL.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([^/]*).mp4$ str.php?vid=$1&auth=$2&hash=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([^/]*).flv$ str.php?vid=$1&auth=$2&hash=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Than you a lot my dear :D :))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have rewrite conditions **after** the rule, since what you have will never match. Besides, you need to be matching against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:start=([^&]+)|)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([^/]*).mp4$ str.php?vid=$1&auth=$2&hash=$3&start=%1

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:start=([^&]+)|)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([^/]*).flv$ str.php?vid=$1&auth=$2&hash=$3&start=%1
```

Note that you have **four** capture groups in the regular expression, three `(.*)` then one `([^/]*)`, and you are only using the first three, and ignoreing the fourth. But if you say that that's working fine, then I guess that's what you want.